# Format specifiers not working, giving RUNTIME ERROR

Tags: c, dev-c++, turbo-c++

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    printf("Enter two numbers : ");
    scanf("%d %d",a,b);
    printf("%d %d",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is this code written in C and saved as New.c giving run time error both in Dev C++ and Turbo C++ compilers?
After the execution of the first printf it takes values and suddenly the screen goes off. Please help me. I am new with C.

Comment: Please read the man page for `scanf`. Should be `scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);` and please enable all compiler warnings too.

Comment: Of course, if you're using Turbo C++, those compiler warnings don't exist. :( Use a modern compiler, please, not one that's ~25 years old.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    printf("Enter two numbers : ");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    printf("%d %d",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

You need '&' before scanning in any of your primitive data types.

When you compile, you're giving the direct value of a and b as though they're memory locations and your program is attempting to follow those values as addresses to store the scanned in values.

This allows you store the literal address in an integer, and COULD work fine. However for what you're trying to do, you want to give the addresses for a and b.

The '&' allows you to pass the address of a variable (passing by reference) to a function, so you can edit the contents outside of your normal scope.

tldr; use an '&' to scan in basic data types (short, int, long, char, float, double). Don' use an '&' to print them out.

Comment: thank you for your help. i have started learning C from yesterday. i have  a strong base in C++ and JAVA. The solution did worked. Thanks again.